# Database Transactions - Keeping some data from rolling back

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, transactions

How can I keep some data from a transaction which is expected to roll back?

Is there a way of telling the transaction not to roll back some lines?

Would executing a stored procedure stop the transaction from rolling back the manipulations in the stored procedure?

Is -saving the data into a variable or table variable which is not in the scope of the transaction- the only method?

Comment: If you want to keep it, you designed something in the wrong way. The "only" way, if you want to swim against the river stream, is to use a database engine that doesn't support transactions. If you wrapped queries in a transaction, it means they all succeed or don't modify the data if one fails. The second your feature or idea has to violate that rule, that means you either have to split queries somehow, re-think your design and feature or simply hack it to incomprehensible code that you won't show to anyone.

Comment: First, you tagged this question both MySQL and TSQL (SQL Server / Sybase): which platform are you asking about? Any answer will probably be platform-specific. Second, why do you want to do this? If you explain your actual purpose, someone may have a solution. There is only one common reason for doing this: you generate audit or debug data within the transaction that should be available even if the transaction rolls back. Finally, the terminology for this feature is an "autonomous transaction", Googling it should give you some useful information.

Comment: @N.B. Not quite true, there is at least one good reason for doing this (see my comment to the OP), and Oracle (for example) [supports it](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions.php).

Comment: @Pondlife - I must admit I never had the need for such a feature, although I admit that it sounds interesting and the fact Oracle does support it - I won't debate whether it's useful or not. My comment to the OP was for MySQL specific use where combining transactional and non-transactional engines enables the possibility of queries retaining their state regardless of transaction state. However, interesting information you provided and I'll definitely read upon it, thank you! :)